# Exchange 2010 certificate missing after completing "Pending certificate signing request!"

Tags: certificate, exchange-2010

After going through the New certificate procedure, creating and importing the .cer file the new certificate simply vanishes.

The same issue applies when I try the same on an Exchange 2013 server.

Screenshot provided for further clarification...

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The cert is broken.  You need to repair it:

Open MMC and add the Certificate Snap-In for the Local Computer account.

Double-Click on the recently imported certificate.
Note: In Windows Server 2008 it will be the certificate missing the golden key beside it.

Select the Details tab.

Click on the Serial Number field and copy that string.
Note: You may use CTRL+C, but not right-click and copy.

Open up a command prompt session. (cmd.exe aka DOS Prompt)

Type: certutil -repairstore my "SerialNumber" (SerialNumber is that which was copied down in step 4.)

After running the above command, go back to the MMC and Right-Click Certificates and select Refresh (or hit F5 in the MMC)

Double-Click on the problem certificate. At the bottom of this window (General tab) it should state: "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate."
Note: In Windows Server 2008 there will be a golden key to the left of the certificate, so there is no need to double-click the certificate.

Now that the Private Key is attached to the certificate, please proceed to enable Exchange Services via Enable-ExchangeCertificate.